# How to save current date and prevent it to change on reload

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm new to javascript. I worked with php before. I have create function which returns current month date, time. I want to save that generated time and prevent it from increment on refresh. but I can't figure out how to do that? can anyone please guide me with this?

```
function getDateForTimer() {
    var date = new Date();
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var month = months[date.getMonth()];
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var todayDate = date.getDate();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();;
    var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();

    return month + ' ' + todayDate + ', ' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + (minutes + 15) + ':' + seconds;
}

// returns => Apr 4, 2020 19:35:37
```

Comment: How much do you want the date to persist? Do you want every user to see their own timestamp from when they first visited? Is it supposed to stay this timestamp for ever, or just for a few hours? There's a few options for where to save the initial timestamp, including a database, the URL, localstorage, and more.

Comment: I want to save that date for 15 - 20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you mean refreshing page in browser, then you would need a PHP session variable (or cookie etc) set that at the end of your script /// At top of script, check for presence of session/cookie. Don't run JS if value present

If you want to lose the stored value then either set the cookie expired date or set another timestamp-value as a session variable (or cookie)

As in comments ... You could use a local text file, or a database instead of cookie/session

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using localStorage.

```
function getPersistentDate() {
    var lastValue = localStorage.getItem('lastTime');
    // If no previous value, or previous value is
    // more than 20 minutes old, set a new one.
    if(!lastValue || Date.now() - lastValue > 20 * 60000) {
        localStorage.setItem('lastTime', Date.now());
        return new Date();
    } else {
        return new Date(lastValue);
    }
}

function getDateForTimer() {
    var date = getPersistentDate();
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var month = months[date.getMonth()];
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var todayDate = date.getDate();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();;
    var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();

    return month + ' ' + todayDate + ', ' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + (minutes + 15) + ':' + seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To persist data in browser, either you can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. Both have their use cases.

LocalStorage will stay till you clean data or delete `programmatically`, `sessionStorage` auto-deleted when the session finished.

note: If you want to maintain session from backend, Use `session cookies` and set an insecure way. So that hackers can't change it. `Read-only`.

```
function getDateForTimer() {
  var date = new Date();
  var months = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sept",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec",
  ];
  var month = months[date.getMonth()];
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var todayDate = date.getDate();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes =
    date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
  var seconds =
    date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();

  return (
    month +
    " " +
    todayDate +
    ", " +
    year +
    " " +
    hours +
    ":" +
    (minutes + 15) +
    ":" +
    seconds
  );
}

const time = getDateForTimer();

// Save last date

localStorage.setItem("lastDate", time);

window.onload = function () {
  // some logic to create and delete time.
  const lastDate = localStorage.getItem("lastDate");
  if (!lastDate) lastDate = getDateForTimer();

  // how to delete
  localStorage.removeItem("lastDate")
};
```